# Is DownloaderService required if I just need to copy files to Internal Storage?

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

If the Play Store already packs the OBB file with the APK, and puts it in the OBB folder, then all I have to do is unpack and copy the files to Internal Storage.

Why would I need to use DownloaderService? It seems like a lot of overhead and complicated code if I can accomplish what I want without it. What would be the advantage of using DownloaderService?

Another question: if my APK upload size is 5 MB, but when I download it from the Play Store the download size is 95 MB. Why is it including the OBB file in the download from the Play Store?

Comment: I thought the point of an expansion pack was that it _wasn't_ packaged with the APK.

Comment: The apk and the obb files are separate, but when you download from the Play Store, it adds up the size for both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely right, in theory you don't need the downloader service if everything is working perfectly. However users often decide to "clean up" their device, either manually, or using so called cleaner apps, most of which don't clean up anything properly. These apps could delete your OBB files, or the user could, even when they shouldn't.

By building the downloader service into your app you can recover the OBBs, even if the user makes a mistake like this, then your app will keep working.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a test. MY OBB size is 157 MB.

When I downloaded from the Play Store I received the message :
Download using Wi-Fi only... This is a large application, etc. It seems it shows that message for download sizes greater than 100 MB.

Play Store is including the OBB.

The download size in the Play Store showed 159 MB. So as I download it shows the progress, for example: 80 MB / 159 MB.

I went to File Manager. The OBB file was in there, showing 157 MB size.

So my answer is: I don't really need the DownloaderService if I can get the data in the OBB file, extract it, and delete it afterwards. I just have to put the copying and unzipping tasks in an AsyncTask and write the progress code.